# CSS background-image url does not work when using brackets

Tags: php, html, css

Use the brackets editor. here

I tried to insert an image into class = portrait div by linking stylecss from index.html, but it will not insert.

Other tutorials use this.

But why is it not working for me?

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My name's lEEGANG</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div clas="portrait"></div>
        <div clas="profile">profile</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body{
    margin: 0; 
}

body{
    background-color: #111;
    color: #999;

}
.portrait {
    background-image: url(images/profile.png);
    height: 200px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the *class* spelling in your HTML code

clas="portrait" --> It should be double s "ss"

It should be::

```
<div class="portrait"> </div>
```

Also include width in css if the div is empty

```
.portrait {
    background-image: url(images/profile.png);
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: @TheRiver강이, Can you please upvote if the solution helped you